# FastAPI multiple database connetions on different models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to achieve a sort-of multi-tenant application inside FastAPI, where some models connect to a different database than others, but no matter what I try, I always run into circular imports.

My file structure is the following:

```
app
 |- database/
    |- models/
       |- api_tokens.py (contains only one class: ApiToken)
       |- users.py (contains only one class: User)
       |- and so on, models are in separate files
    |- base.py
    |- session.py
 |- routers/
    |- contains routes, each one in a separate file
 |- main.py
```

The contents of the `app/database/session.py`:

```py
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from typing import Generator

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://" + os.getenv('DB_USERNAME') + ":" + os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD') + "@" + os.getenv('DB_HOST') + "/" + os.getenv('DB_DATABASE') + "?charset=utf8mb4"
SQLALCHEMY_CUSTOMERS_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://" + os.getenv('CUSTOMERS_DB_USERNAME') + ":" + os.getenv('CUSTOMERS_DB_PASSWORD') + "@" + os.getenv('CUSTOMERS_DB_HOST') + "/" + os.getenv('CUSTOMERS_DB_DATABASE') + "?charset=utf8mb4"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
customers_engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_CUSTOMERS_DATABASE_URI)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind = engine)

def get_db() -> Generator:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

And the `app/database/base.py`:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Query
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

from .session import get_db

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    session = next(get_db())

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key = True)



class ApiTokensBase(DeclarativeBase):
    session = next(get_db())

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key = True)
```

My question is, how can I achieve that the `ApiToken` model (extending the `ApiTokensBase` class) use the connection specified in the `SQLALCHEMY_CUSTOMERS_DATABASE_URI`?

**What I've tried so far:**

I tried following the documentation of SQLAchemy on this topic (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.params.binds), and checked if I can implement what I want based on this example: https://gist.github.com/lmyyao/37157fff3ba90889d7c1e0f9dc774253, but I always run into circular imports.

I used the following code in the `app/database/session.py` file:

```py
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from typing import Generator

from app.database.base import Base, ApiTokensBase

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://" + os.getenv('DB_USERNAME') + ":" + os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD') + "@" + os.getenv('DB_HOST') + "/" + os.getenv('DB_DATABASE') + "?charset=utf8mb4"
SQLALCHEMY_CUSTOMERS_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://" + os.getenv('CUSTOMERS_DB_USERNAME') + ":" + os.getenv('CUSTOMERS_DB_PASSWORD') + "@" + os.getenv('CUSTOMERS_DB_HOST') + "/" + os.getenv('CUSTOMERS_DB_DATABASE') + "?charset=utf8mb4"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
customers_engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_CUSTOMERS_DATABASE_URI)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind = engine, binds = {
    Base: engine,
    ApiTokensBase: customers_engine,
})

def get_db() -> Generator:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Thanks for everyones help in advance.